# Loading fetched rows into php array

Tags: php, sql-server, ajax

Below I am trying to send an ajax request when the page loads to get the results of the productID and productName in a given table. There are about 50k rows to be pulled and i've run into some time delay issues due to the organizing and handling of the array on the serverside(php). Looking at the code below I am able to get the first 10k rows to display on the console without a problem but when i query the entire table for all the results, the console returns a blank object, any possible workarounds for this?

```
function loadProducts() {
   jQuery.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                data:{'x':'x' },
                url: 'performanceHelper/loadProductList.php',
                dataType: 'text',

                success: function (result, textstatus) {
                   //Removing reference in Firebase   
                    console.log(result);
                }
                });
}
window.onload = loadProducts();
```

PHP code

```
require_once("../connect.php");


$sql = "SELECT productID, productDesc FROM products";


  $temp = $dbh->query($sql);


  $results = $temp->fetchAll();


   echo json_encode($results);
```

Comment: could be a problem related to the console buffer display size .. which browser do you use ?

Comment: What on earth are you going to do with 50,000 items in the browser, surely not show them to a user?

Comment: I suspect it simply lacks memory enough for `$results = $temp->fetchAll();` so ending with a 500 error.

Comment: There's 50000 products and the user can select each one to receive further specifics, I think I'll go with @AceKYD pagination answer, if anyone has any other workarounds thatd be appreciated

Comment: @cFreed I tried increasing the memory limit in my php ini configs

Comment: Even if you tried increasing memory limit you can't be sure it's enough. So did you checked logs to ensure you don't get any error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like @RiggsFolly mentioned in the comments, what on earth do you want to do with 50000 items in the browser????

However if you have to, since you can get 10k without any issues like you mentioned, i'll suggest you try pagination... create a function to get the items by sending `start` and `limit` as parameters.

This way you dont have to send 50k items at once but you can still get your data.